# enable binary logging Azure mysql server

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

I have created one Azure MYSQL server (DaaS/PaaS). Now I have to enable binary logging. I have checked the Azure MYSQL server parameter & I couldn't find this specific setting.May I know, How can I enable this log ? Currently Log_bin = OFF.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible on Azure MYSQL Service (PaaS / DaaS). We have to setup Mysql on Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

in case of you are using AzureChina, it's possible to enable it.

```
  if your mysql is only master node, you need ask request to enable it by azure customer service center, create ticket to them.
  if your mysql has replica node, the binlog parameter should be enabled by default.
```

check if it works:

```
mysql> show variables like '%log_bin%';
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                        |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| log_bin                         | ON                           |
| log_bin_basename                | c:\work\binlogs\mysql-bin    |
| log_bin_index                   | c:\mysqldata\mysql-bin.index |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                          |
| log_bin_use_v1_row_events       | OFF                          |
| sql_log_bin                     | ON                           |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy for the info. We are not using AzureChina.

Answer (score 0):

As I just check it, You can create temporary replication server in azure portal web and then delete it.

It seams that azure change master server configuration and enable the binary log for replication purpose and this setting seams to be permanent, even when you delete all replica servers.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set the log bit (`log_bit=ON`). Just [create a replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-read-replicas-portal#create-a-read-replica) of your Azure MySQL server. You can delete the replica when it's created, the log bit will remain set.